# ReactJs - Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sum, appendchild

I know this one has been posted over and over on Stack Overflow. But I can't figure out how to fix this in my code.

Basically, I'm building a simple donation web app in ReactJS.  Very basic at this point.

1) There's a short form, where you enter a number (Form.JS).  And then this value is parsed onto ProgressBar.js.

2) I'm then calculating the total donations and inserting this total/tally/sum, into the page.

Now what I'm trying to do, is add some styling to my bar.  For example, if the total donations are < 10, add div, color red, width: 10px.

But I keep getting the error appendChild property is null.  I think this might because my code is running, before the sum has calculated?  I'm just not sure how to fix this.

Here's both my code snippets below:

**FORM.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bulma';

const Form = ({ handleSubmit, handleChange}) => {

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div className="field">
      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
      <input className="input"
        type="number"
        placeholder="number"
        name="number"
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
      />
    </div>
    <button className="button is-primary">Give Now</button>
  </form>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

**PROGRESSBAR.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bulma';

const ProgressBar = ({donated}) => {

  const numbers = donated.map(Number);

  // FUNCTION TO CALCULATE TOTAL DONATIONS
  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  const sum = numbers.reduce(add, 0);

  // IF SUM DONATIONS ARE LESS THAN THE VALUE OF 10, ADD THIS CSS TO THE JSX
  if (sum < 10) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.background = 'red';
    div.style.width = '10px';
    div.style.height = '50px';
    div.style.float = 'left';
    document.querySelector('.bar').appendChild(div);
 }
// JSX
  return (
    <div>
      <p>donations made so far: {donated.length}</p>
      <p>£{sum}</p>
      <div className="bar"></div>
      <ul>
       {donated.map((donated, i) => <li key={i}>{donated}</li>)}
     </ul>
  </div>
 );
};
export default ProgressBar;
```

**APP.JS**

```
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
   number: '',
   donated: []
 };

 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 // we need to bind otherwise this is undefined
}

//HANDLE FUNCTIONS
handleChange(e) {
this.setState({ number: e.target.value }, () => 
console.log(this.state.number));
 }

handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({donated: this.state.donated.concat(this.state.number)});
}

render() {
return (
  <main>
    <section className="section">
      <h1 className="is-size-2">DONATE FOR A GOOD CAUSE</h1>
      <ProgressBar donated={this.state.donated} />
      <Form handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
    </section>
  </main>
 );
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('root')
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running before the nodes are created, so it can't manipulate them. But you generally don't need to do DOM manipulation like this in React. Just put the logic in your JSX, e.g.:

```
<div className="bar">
    {sum < 10 && (
        <div style={{background: 'red'}} />
    )}
</div>
```

Comment: ok, thank you.... that didn't work... :/ . What I'm trying to do, is add a block everytime a donation is submitted...

Comment: It's not clear from your code how these two components are connected. But what you should probably do is keep track of the number of donations in a state variable, pass it to your progress component as a property, and loop that number of times in the JSX, displaying a block for each one.

Comment: ok, I got it working... i basically im just for looping through the array of donations... but i'm not doing it in the JSX... is this bad practice?

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i < 10) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.background = 'red';
      div.style.width = '50px';
      div.style.height = '50px';
      div.style.float = 'left';
      document.querySelector('.bar').appendChild(div);
    }
  }

Comment: Yeah, you should hardly be doing any DOM manipulation at all with React. That's kind of the point. You could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486964/4321).

Comment: Ok, so I am passing the number of donations.  That's being passed through as "donations".  Because of my component a simple functional component though, I don't think i can use state, correct?  thank yoyu.